# Generated pdf using iText. Textfields show data after field focus

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iText to generate a pdf with textfields populated with data, from an ASP.NET web form. For some reason, when the pdf is generated, the textfields show Empty, but when I put the cursor on the field, the text shows. If I click somewhere else, then the text in the textfield disappears again. This is the code, adding a textfield called "Field_0_0". The text "hello1" is set to the textfield, but it doesn't display until clicking the textbox. The only way to get the text in the textfield is by typing something, and then the text stays there after losing focus.

```
        byte[] templatebytes = null;


        //Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35)
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);

        doc.Open();

        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("This is my first paragraph");
        Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my first phrase");
        Chunk chunk_ = new Chunk("This is my first chunk");

        doc.Add(para);
        doc.Add(pharse);
        doc.Add(chunk_);

        doc.Close();

        templatebytes = stream.ToArray();


        //==============================================================================================================================================
        Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream(templatebytes);

        byte[] finalbytes = null;

        using (MemoryStream outputPdfStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(stream2);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper pdfStamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputPdfStream);

            TextField tf1 = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 100), "Field_0_0");


            tf1.DefaultText = "     ";
            tf1.Options = TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.VISIBLE;
            tf1.TextColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
            tf1.FontSize = 10;
            tf1.BorderWidth = 1;
            tf1.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLUE;

            pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(tf1.GetTextField(), 1);


            pdfStamper.Close();

            finalbytes = outputPdfStream.ToArray();
        }






        //====================================== set data ========================================
        Stream stream3 = new MemoryStream(finalbytes);

        byte[] finalbytes3 = null;


        using (MemoryStream outputPdfStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(stream3);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper pdfStamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputPdfStream);



            //Set fields with data
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields form = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            IDictionary<string, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item> fields = form.Fields;


            string value = "Hello1"; //$"Line1{Environment.NewLine}Line2";

            form.SetField("Field_0_0", value); //$"Line1{Environment.NewLine}Line2"

            pdfStamper.Close();

            finalbytes3 = outputPdfStream.ToArray();
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GeneratedPDF.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", finalbytes3.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(finalbytes3);
        Response.End();
```

Hopefully I explained this right. I can't find a solution online to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Which `iTextSharp` version do you use?

Comment: iTextSharp 5.5.9. I installed it as a nuget package today

Comment: @dlabarca I know it's been a while but did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set property of pdfStamper follow this:

```
pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = false;
```